# Creating new application version for Amazon Elastic beanstalk existing application using java api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to automate the process of creating application version for an existing elastic beanstalk application through java api and command line arguments.

while implementing createApplicationVersion() of AWSElasticBeanstalkClient I am getting error for the below code snipplet.
Note: I am passing the endpoint for AWSElasticBeanstalkClient as US East-1 (N.Virginia) or the environment url for the existing application.

```
    ArrayList<String> s3SourceBundleList = AmazonS3BucketUploadApp.doBucketUploadFromLocal(sourceLocation);
    String bucketName = s3SourceBundleList.get(0);
    String keyName = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(s3SourceBundleList.get(1), "UTF-8");
    //String keyName = s3SourceBundleList.get(1);
    S3Location s3SourceBundle = new S3Location();
    s3SourceBundle.setS3Bucket(bucketName);
    s3SourceBundle.setS3Key(keyName);
    createApplicationVersionRequest.setSourceBundle(s3SourceBundle);
    createApplicationVersionRequest.setDescription("New version");

    appVersionResultObject = awsBeanstalkclient.createApplicationVersion(createApplicationVersionRequest);
```

Error:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (ParseError at [row,col]:[6,1]
```

and one more error is

```
AWS service: AmazonElasticBeanstalk AWS Request ID: null AWS service unavailable.
```

Please suggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing the client (check logs output - enabling logger `org.apache.http.wire` to TRACE could help)?

If you want an idea, peek at this source:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/awseb-deployment-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/ingenieux/jenkins/plugins/awsebdeployment/Deployer.java

It contains all you need to build and deploy into AWS EB :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am getting connection refused error now for my standalone java application for automating create application version fro beanstalk. The AWSElasticBeanStalkClient is initialized by below code. 
    
AWSElasticBeanstalkClient awsBeanstalkclient = CommandlineApp
    .getAmazonElasticBeanstalkClient(awsconfig, accessKeyID, secretAccessKey);
  awsBeanstalkclient.setEndpoint(property.getProperty("ebsEndPoint")); Please help.

Comment: Read this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-logging.html

then enable wire debugging as I've mentioned above. review, discard the keys, and paste into a git ok?